# If two functions are as given below, what would f(x) and specifically , f(1) be as the limit h goes to 0?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, definite-integrals

\begin{aligned}
& g(x)= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } x \in[-1,1] \\
0 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases} \\
& f(x)=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2 h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} g(y) d y .
\end{aligned}

Graphically, as I understand it's the equivalent of the area of a function in $y$ between the points $(x+h)$ and $(x-h)$, which would go to "some constant times $xh$" and then $f(x)$ becomes $x$.

I'm not sure if my understanding is wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do not post links to images. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations.

Answer (score 2):

Let's tackle the $f(1)$. The more general case can be done in similar fashion once you know how to find $f(1)$. Observe that $\dfrac{d}{dh} (2h) = 2$, and for $0< h < 1$, $\dfrac{d}{dh} \displaystyle \int_{1-h}^{1+h} g(x)dx=\dfrac{d}{dh} \left(-\displaystyle \int_{1}^{1-h} g(x)dx + \displaystyle \int_{1}^{1+h} g(x)dx\right)= -(-g(1-h)) + g(1+h)=g(1-h)+g(1+h)$. Thus using L'hospital rule we obtain: $f(1) = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{1-h}^{1+h} g(x)dx}{2h}= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(1+h)+g(1-h)}{2}=\dfrac{0+1}{2}= \dfrac{1}{2}.$

Comment: That's a nice way to handle the signs. It looks fine to me.